# Excel Macro loop sheet selection issue

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to coding and have been trying to get this loop to work for some time without much success. I need this macro to loop through each sheet excluding the first two sheets (master and calculations), and move the data to either the Master or Calculations sheet as specified. Thank you for any help you're able to give in advance.

```
Dim i As Integer

Dim WS_Count As Integer

While i > 2
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("A2:R2").Select
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlDown, copyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("A:G").Select
    Selection.Insert shift:=xlRight, copyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
'Calculational sheet formating
    sheet (i).Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Subject & Number: Data Input to Master Sheet
' Locations: Data File: B7 Master: A2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B7").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Date: Data Input to Master Sheet
' Locations: Data File: C5 Master: B2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("C5").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("B2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Experiment Name
' Locations: Data File: B8 Master: C2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("C2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Group Number
' Locations: Data File: B9  Master: D2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B9").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("D2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Box Number: 2 or 4
' Locations: Data File: B10 Master: E2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("E2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Total Time in box (S): Over all experiment time
' Locations: Data File: B27 Master: F2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B27").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("F2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Time In Box (E): Sum( all E )- Values are summed in the calculations sheet 
(A1:A20,F1:F20)
' Locations: Data File: C32:G32, Calculations: A2:G2 Master: G2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("C32:G32", Range("C32:G32").End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range(A2).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F10") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A2:E2", 
    Range("A2:E2").End(xlDown)))
    Range("F10").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("F11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F11").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("G2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Entries (J): count (# tunnel time stamps)
' locations: Data File: B21 Master: H2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("B21").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("H2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Average Time In Box: Average (all E )
' Locations: Data File: C32:G32, Calculations: A22 Master: I2
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("C32:G32", Range("C32:G32").End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("A22").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F30") = WorksheetFunction.Average(Range("A2:E2", 
    Range("A2:E2").End(xlDown)))
    Range("F30").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("F31").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F31").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Master").Select
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
' Trail Number: (A) Data Input to Master sheet
' Locations: Data File: B14 Master: J2
Sheets(i).Select
Range("B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("J2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Lever Presses: (B) Data Input to Master sheet
' Locations: Data File: B15 Master: K2
Sheets(i).Select
Range("B15").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("K2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Food cup checks (K):
' Locations: Data File: B22 Master: L2
Sheets(i).Select
Range("B22").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("L2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Pellet reward numbers's (P/O)
' Locations: Data File: B23 Master: M2
Sheets(i).Select
Range("B23").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("M2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
' Food Retrieval latency: Food cup stamp - lever time stamp / total trials * 
100
' Locations: Data File:((C35:G35)-(C83:G83))/B14*100, Calculations A42, A62, 
F41, F42, F43, F44, F45  Master: N2
Sheets(i).Select
Range("C35:G35", Range("C35:G35").End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("A42").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets(i).Select
    Range("C83:G83", Range("C83:G83").End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Calculations").Select
    Range("A62").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("F41") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A42:G42", 
    `Range("A42:G42").End(xlDown)))
    Range("F42") = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("A62:G62", 
    Range("A62:A62").End(xlDown)))
        Range("F43").Value = Range("F41") - Range("F42")
            Sheets(i).Select
            Range("B14").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("Calculations").Select
            Range("F44").Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Range("F45").Value = (Range("F43") / Range("F44")) * 100
                Range("F45").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Calculations").Select
                Range("F46").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("F46").Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Cut
                Sheets("Master").Select
                Range("N2").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
   ' File Name
   ' Location: Data File:C1 Master: O2
   Sheets(i).Select
Range("C1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Master").Select
Range("O2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Wend

'Exit Handler updates the view screen so that your on the last sheet of data 
added to the file and exits the subroutine
ExitHandler:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set wkbAll = Nothing
Set wkbTemp = Nothing
Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
MsgBox Err.Description
Resume ExitHandler

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a massive chunk of code. I'm answering this here for clarity instead of commenting even though it's not an "answer" to your problem... it might show how you can condense your code and reduce a lot of error potential.

Instead of:

```
Sheets(i).Select
Range("B14").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Calculations").Select
Range("F44").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

You can simply put:

```
Sheets("Calculations").Range("F44").Value = Sheets(i).Range("B14").Value
```

If you do this to your code chunk it'll reduce the size by 3-4 times and make it a lot easier for both yourself and the forum readers to help you.

You don't need to select worksheets and copy and paste, you can just directly tell sheet xyz that its range A1 value is another sheets range A1 value.

**Edit:** You can also tell a range that its formula is the same as another's, if that's what you require. e.g. `Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Formula = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").Formula`

Either way your code could be simplified quite a lot if you look in to getting rid of `Select`ing and it makes everyone's job easier!

Comment: Setting a cell's `Value` to another cell's `Value` is different to copying one cell to another - a copy/paste will, by default, copy formulas (and formatting) rather than values.  I suspect that the OP **is** just trying to copy values, but you should probably add a warning to that effect to the "answer" just in case they aren't.  (Their code could still be simplified by using `Sheets(i).Range("B14").Copy Sheets("Calculations").Range("F44")`, etc.)

Comment: That's a good observation, and of course you can sub `Value` for `Formula` in the same way, depening on the needs. I'll update my non-answer to reflect.